# Access to localhost from other machine - Angular

Tags: angular, localhost

**Background**

Most developers often use two or more desktops and laptops when they're working on a project. Same for me, and now I'm working on an Angular project.

**GOAL**

I want to access localhost:4200 from another device, so I can check the UI updates without switching windows on a device.

I took some research and tried the below angular-CLI command.

```
ng serve --host=MyLocalIP
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

But no luck until yet. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Using `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` command has solved my problem.
Type 192.168.x.x:4200 to get access to the app from another machine.

Also, check for firewall rules on client and server (disable firewall temporally or create a rule to allow traffic)

Comment: thanks for your reply, I already tried this, that doesn't work, maybe cause of firewall?

Comment: @brucelin Are you able to `ping` the IP address that you're trying to reach? The command is just `ping` + the IP you're trying to reach

Comment: yeah maybe.. turn off firewall activity,and try it again?

Comment: @seyidyagmur, I edit the post again, I tried after turn off the firewall, but same, still getting ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: it is because your computer is not accesible from other computers in your network.try turn off windows firewall for public network like this link. https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-disable-the-windows-firewall-2624505

Comment: @seyidyagmur, thanks, was my fault on the firewall settings. By the way is there any way to allow only this port? Since both desktop connected to the internet and I want to keep the PC safe. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I have not tried it yet coz I am online in mobile right now,But I'll try it ASAP.This is a useful question.someone answered this question in this link https://superuser.com/a/144543

Comment: One of my friend have the same issue after applying 0.0.0.0, It's resolved by Turning off Firewall, It's mostly happening in window machine

Answer (score 17):

Two options are there

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

To check, if this is not working, 1st try to hit from the same computer where you run **ng serve**, to get to know if you can access through the firewall

```
ng serve --host 192.168.X.X
```

192.168.X.X is the IP address of my pc(you can use ipconfig(windows), ifconfig(Linux) to see your IP)
After that, you can access 192.1668.X.X:4200 instead of localhost:4200

Nothing related:- Even if you change some code and server refresh to show updated code, it will refresh in other machines too

If you can not able to access 192.168.X.X:4200. You may be in a network where firewall protection is blocking. SO, connect to your personal network and check

Answer (score 1):

ng serve --host 192.168.X.X --port 9000

Comment: you can provide any port of your choice by using --port

Answer (score 0):

Using ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 will allow you to connect to the ng serve using your ip instead of localhost.

NOTE

In newer versions of the cli, you have to provide your local ip address instead

NOTE

In newer versions of the cli you can use 0.0.0.0 as the ip again to host it for anyone on your network to talk to.

As a side note Make sure your connection is set to Public in your OS settings.